# Why does setvbuf() function adds growths to the buffer in C?

Tags: c, file, buffer

i'm trying to store the content of a file on a buffer using `setvbuf()`function in c, this is the code to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt","r+");
char buff[BUFSIZ];
char buff2[BUFSIZ];

setvbuf(fp,buff2,_IOFBF,BUFSIZ);
fgets(buff,BUFSIZ,fp);
printf("%s\n",buff2);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

and this is the file's content

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

but when i execute the code, the console shows:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3 3
```

where it comes from the additional char at the end of output?.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or in what manner an implementation uses the buffer provided to `setvbuf` is unspecified. Attempting to derive anything meaningful from its contents while it's associated with a stdio FILE is not something you should be doing.

Comment: Any suggestion that replaces `setvbuf`?.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is *intentionally* no way to peek at the stdio buffer contents; that's part of the abstraction/encapsulation that allows for various implementation choices.